# EJS not rendering page on display

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

PLEASE SOMEONE

Below is the code for a login app that I was trying out, and as I'm sure you can gather I'm a real noob at this, I think I did everything right because there weren't any errors thrown, but I came across this problem, and its been killing me.
I've been wracking my brain for an answer I just can't get the ejs to render the view. Upon inspecting the network shows the fetch item to be correct but It just doesn't render.

obj.js

```
const form = document.getElementById('Signinform');
form.addEventListener('submit', Signin);

async function Signin(event){
event.preventDefault();
const email = document.getElementById('email').value
const password = document.getElementById('password').value

const result = await fetch('/user/signin',{
  method:'POST',
  headers:{
    'Content-Type':'application/json',
    'Accept': 'text/html'        
  },
  body:JSON.stringify({
    email,
    password
  })
})//.then((res)=>res.json())

//console.log(result)
```

};

User.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router =express.Router();

//mongodb user model
const user = require('./../models/user');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');



//password handler
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

//making the router use request body as json


//Signup
router.post('/signup',(req,res)=>{
let{name, email, password, dateofBirth} = req.body;
name = name.trim();
email = email.trim();
password = password.trim();
dateofBirth = dateofBirth.trim();
if(name == "" || email == "" || password == "" || dateofBirth == ""){
    res.json({
        status:"FAILED",
        message:"Empty input fields"
    });
}else if(!/^[a-zA-Z]*$/.test(name)) {
    res.json({
        status:"FAILED",
        message:"Invalid name entered"
    });
}else if(!/^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/.test(email)){
    res.json({
        status:"FAILED",
        message:"Invalid name entered"
    });
}else if(! new Date(dateofBirth).getTime()){
    res.json({
        status:"FAILED",
        message:"Invalid date of Birth entered"
    });
}else if(password.length < 8){
    res.json({
        status:"FAILED",
        message:"Password is too short!!"
    })
}else{
    //Checking if user already exists
    user.find({email}).then(result=>{
        if (result.length){
            //if user already exists
            res.json({
                status: "FAILED",
                message: "User with the provided email still exists"
            })
        } else{
            //Try to create a new user

            //password handling
            const saltRounds =10;
            bcrypt.hash(password,saltRounds).then(hashedPassword =>{
                const newUser = new user({
                    name,
                    email,
                    password:hashedPassword,
                    dateofBirth
                });

                newUser.save().then(result=>{
                    res.json({
                        status: "SUCCESS",
                        message:"Signup succesful",
                        data:result,
                    })
                }).catch(err=>{
                    res.json({
                        status:"FAILED",
                        message:"An error occured while trying to save User"
                    })
                })
            }).catch(err=>{
                res.json({
                    status:"FAILED",
                    message:"An error occured while hashing password!"
                })
            })  
        }

    }).catch(err=>{
        console.log(err);
        res.json({
            status:"FAILED",
            message:"An error occurered while checking for existing user"
        })
    })

  }


 })

//Rendering Sign in page
router.get('/signin',async(req,res)=>{
res.render('user_signin');
});

//Signin
 router.post('/signin', async(req,res)=>{
let{email, password}=req.body;
email = email.trim();
password = password.trim();

if(email == "" || password == ""){
    res.json({
     status:"FAILED",
     message:"Empty Credentials supplied"
    });

}else{
    //Check if user exists
    user.find({email})
    .then(data =>{
        if(data.length){
        //user exists
const hashedPassword = data[0].password;
bcrypt.compare(password,hashedPassword).then(result=>{
    if(result){
        //password matches
    // res.json({
    //  status:"SUCCESS",
    //  message:"Signin succesful",
    //  data : data
    // });
    res.render('signinsuccess',{name : data[0].name});
}else{
    res.json({
        status: "FAILED",
        message: "Invalid password entered"
    });
}
    })
.catch(err=>{
    res.json({
    status: "FAILED",
    message:"An error occured while comparing passwords"

    })

})

        }else{
            res.json({
                status:"FAILED",
                message:"Invalid Credentials entered"
            })
        }
        
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        res.json({
            status:"FAILED",
            message:"An error occured while checking for existing user"
        })
    })
}
})

module.exports = router;
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
//getting database
require('./config/db.js');

const app = require('express')();
const port = 3000;
app.set('view engine','ejs');

const UserRouter =require('./api/user');
app.use('/assets', express.static('assets'));


//For accepting post form data
const bodyparser = require('express').json;
app.use(bodyparser());

app.use('/user', UserRouter)

app.listen(port,()=>{
console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
 })
```

PLEASE HELP

Comment: what is `signinsuccess` ? `res.render` requires ejs files to be declared in full *viz* `res.render('somthing.ejs')`

Comment: I assumed after declaring the view engine the render function automatically assumes the entered name as an ejs. But upon your suggestion I tried changing it  but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: What debugging have you done? Have you checked if all the intended functions are running properly by using `console.log` logging?

Comment: Mmmmm so to give you context  user. js handles the body of the sign in and sign up sections, which was originally debugged and checked to be working through console logging and using postman to view actual functionality. But my goal now is to create a front end for the back end already created , and the first problem I run across is that the ejs doesnt render.

Comment: what is the url you are trying?

Comment: Oh and I think I should clarify that I have only tried implementing ejs in the sign in section. My bad for not mentioning that, I gave up after the signinsuccess.ejs didn't render

Comment: localhost:3000/user/signin is the one I want to affect.... I can change the view of this url to signinsuccess.ejs right?

Comment: `signinsuccess.ejs` is for POST .. `user_signin.ejs` is for opening the URL in browser. You have not defined the routes access properly. Also, bodyparser declaration is wrong `server.js`

Comment: A tried and tested way of debugging is to check if the variables that are being used in functions are actually what you are expecting them to be.

Comment: Can you let me know how I can go about doing defining the route access properly please?